# Stored Procedure doesn't give output

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have created a very simple procedure as follows.

```
delimiter $$   
create procedure A()   
begin   
select * from user;   
end $$  
delimiter ;
```

I am calling procedure as

```
call A()
```

This doesn't give any output but if i execute the same procedure using `phpmyadmin` interface the procedure returns the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless and until you perform some print operation from your procedure, it wouldn't print anything by just using SELECT statement. To see the result o the SELECT statement try to print and see the result

Comment: When i execute the same procedure using phpmyadmin procedure interface it fetches the result.